# Runtime of SVD in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, runtime, svd

I have to compute the singular value decomposition of very large matrices in Matlab for simulation of optical systems. I tested my program with lower sampling (i.e. smaller matrices). Before I run my final simulation I would like to estimate what matrix size I can get away with for a given simulation time.

**Does anyone know what the runtime of SVD in Matlab is?** Or alternative has anyone tried it and observed the trend for really large matrices?
Optional: is the function svds(...) maybe faster? It might be sufficient for me to only return the first 100 singular values and vectors.

Comment: Theoretical time complexity is usually asymptotic, so I don't see what practical use you can extract from it. There is usually a constant multiplying any complexity behavior, and if you don't know that constant, what will you do with any theoretical result?

Comment: @ItamarKatz If I know the asymptotic complexity and a sample runtime can't I estimate the runtime in the asymptotic limit? It doesn't need to be precise, I'd just like to know how large I can make my sample size while still having a reasonable runtime.

Comment: Do you also need U,V matrices?

Comment: @percusse if possible yes, but if you know about a fast method that just gives singular methods that would be interesting too

Comment: The singular values are roughly O(mn^2). In case U and V are required it is proportional to O(xm^2 n + yn^3) where x and y are some constants depending on the algorithm used. This is pretty much a done subject with LAPACK libraries though. If you have structure in your matrices you can shave off some time for example http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node32.html and http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node53.html